# Lightning RadioGroup not getting preselected value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, radiogroup

I've a problem loading selected value in a radio group. This is my code

```
<lightning:radioGroup
         aura:id="{!question.Id}"
         name="{!question.Id}"
         label="{!question.E3_Question__c}"
         options="{!question.domain}"
         value="{!question.E3_Answer__c}"
         />
```

question.domain are the options of the radio button. Something like this

[{label:"Yes", value:100}, {label:"No", value:0}]

This question is displayed correctly and stored in question.E3_Answer__c field. But when I load this questions I want that the radiogroup load the answer and select the options. But this is not happening. ¿What could be the problem?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it !. This is the problem.

This is my domain

```
[
    {'label': 'Si', 'value': 0},
    {'label': 'No', 'value': 100}
]
```

But when this radiogroup component was trying to compare the value that I got from the question object and the value of the domain they where differents. ¿Why?. Because my E3_Answer__c field in my question object was type "text" and value was "number" ... so 100 != "100" and the value couln't been choosed.... My mistake !

Answer (score 1):

You code will be looking like this

```
<aura:component controller="QuestionAnswerClass" access="global" >  
      <aura:attribute name="Questions" type="List"/>  
   <aura:attribute name="radioGrpValue" type="List"/>   
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>  
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.Questions}" var="ques">  
     <lightning:radioGroup name="{!ques.QuestionText__c}"  
                           label="{! ques.QuestionText__c}"   
                           options="{!ques.Answers__r}"  
                           value="{! v.radioGrpValue}"  
                           type="radio"  
                           required="true"/>  
   </aura:iteration>   
 </aura:component>
```

For detailed explanation, refer my blog post: [Displaying lightning:radioGroup dynamically from SOQL query](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2018/07/displaying-lightningradiogroup.html)